# Firebase: Cannot find module '@firebase/component'

Tags: firebase

Начал изучать Google cloud functions для Firebase с самого начала по мануалу:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0

Сделал все в точности как там описано, сделал deploy, функции благополучно залились на сервер, запускаю и получаю ошибку:

Cannot find module '@firebase/component'

На моем рабочем компьютере - Windows 10 и nodeJS версии 10.

Answer (score 0):

Писал в поддержку Google, они предложили по новой установить пакеты, которые я только что установил - естественно не помогло.

**Что решило проблему**
В мануале незатейливо советуют поставить nvm (node version manager)
Ставить ее надо отсюда по ссылке "download"

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Наша цель поставить nodeJS версии 8
Для этого надо установить nvm
Дать команду nvm list и убедиться что у Вас скорее всего стоит NodJS 13 версии :)
ОК!

набираем:
nvm install 8.16.2 
Это самый последний релиз 8 версии

8 версия грузится и устанавливается.
Даем команду 
nvm use 8.16.2

Также можно почитать статью:
https://canonium.com/articles/managing-node-versions-with-windows-nvm/

**Внимание!**
После установки старой версии NodeJS все пакеты надо ставить заново!
В частности не забудьте по новой установить:
npm install -g firebase-tools

Далее проходим мануал с нуля и получаем долгожданную работающую функцию.

P.S.
Обратите внимание что для использования GCP (Google cloud platform ) - то есть наших функций необходимо подключить платежный account.

Если Вы этого сразу не сделаете - то в журнале ошибок для функций Вы увидите вежливое напоминание про это, а Ваша функция выдаст ошибку.